# Font sizing based on size of region (i.e., div)

Tags: html, css, font-size

I am aware of vw units, however, these are based on the size of the viewport, i.e., the entire screen. What if I need a font-size to be large enough to fit a particular width of a div.

Is that possible?

Any solution or workarounds if it's not?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no CSS property that bases text size on the element. You need javascript...something like FitText.js

Comment: Hmm. Not sure why the down score is being clicked. If no such thing, then that's the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with user1902183 that there is no need to downvote this question as its perfectly legitimate.
I would suggest taking a look at the rem unit.
rem stands for relative em.
As most developers know, an em is fixed according to device. For example, in a browser 1em = 16px. On mobile devices this may be a smaller figure.
With a relative em the font size is dependent on the parent I believe but investigate this. This may be the closest to what you are trying to achieve without resorting to JavaScript.